# map array based on another array data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two arrays data I'm just trying to get the data of array two based on the same ID
example

```
import React from 'react';

const data = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "One",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Two",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  },
]
const dataTwo = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "color": "red"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "color": "blue"
  },
]
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
     {data.map((tweet)=> 
    <ul key={tweet.id}>
            <li>{tweet.title} <b>Color:</b> I want to put the color here</li>
     </ul>
     )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

if id of dataTwo `===` id of data so I want to get the color for the same item

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry for that I've been searching for a while but I couldn't find an appropriate solution , maybe I've found something but I didn't recognize it since I'm just a beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.find`:

```
{data.map((tweet)=> {
    const { color = "default-color" } = dataTwo.find(item => item.id === tweet.id) || {};
    return <ul key={tweet.id}>
            <li>{tweet.title} <b>Color:</b> { color }</li>
     </ul>
})}
```

Or you can change `dataTwo` so that it is an object (map):

```
const dataTwo = {
    1: "red"
    2: "blue"
  };
```

And then access it directly:

```
{data.map((tweet)=>
     <ul key={tweet.id}>
            <li>{tweet.title} <b>Color:</b> { dataTwo[tweet.id] || 'default-color' }</li>
     </ul>
)}
```

Comment: Really thank you for your answer, I'm very new in ReactJS I tried the code it's not working with no console error https://codesandbox.io/s/p3n63oo2lx

Comment: @Lauradelgado sorry about that, I forgot the `return` when I changed the arrow function for the `map`.  I've updated :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a object of dataTwo with key as id and value as color. Use this object to get color while looping

```
var dataTwoObj = {};
dataTwo.reduce((data)=>{
    dataTwoObj[data.id] = data.color;
});
data.map((tweet)=> {
    const color = dataTwoObj[item.id];
    <ul key={tweet.id}>
            <li>{tweet.title} <b>Color:</b> { color }</li>
     </ul>
     )
```